# Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.painless.WriterConstants on Elasticsearch 5.6.16 and with a dependency to jayway

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, jayway

I have Elasticsearch in version 5.6.16. I have added a jayway 2.5.0 as dependency to the project and then got Elasticsearch error:

```
NoClassDefFoundError Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.painless.WriterConstants
```

I was trying to find incompatibile versions of jayway or somethings what jayway uses with Elasticsearch but with positive result.

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of conflicts with asm used by Painless compiler in Elasticsearch (asm:asm-debug-all). To get Elasticsearch working also et.minidev:accessors-smart need to be excluded. Without accessors-smart jayway almost doesn't work.